# Star Wars Squadrons Why is my Cockpit so Zoomed In?

Tags: monitor, star-wars-squadrons

I'm having weird issues, my cockpit is zoomed in, which removes the advantage of the republics wide field of view.  for instance, this is the ywing bomber from a youtube gameplay video: [image]

and heres me in the ywing:

[image]

sorry for the black lines, I had a hard time making the image less than 2 mb, however you can clearly see that my field of view is way lower than it should be.  In the xwing I can't even see the hologram when ardo is talking.  What's going on?  (my screen is 1080x1024)

Comment: Are you using a High DPI screen? If so, there's a possibility the game correctly detects the full resolution, but doesn't correctly report High DPI support, so the OS might upscale the frame, which causes only part of it being visible. If that's the case, using exclusive fullscreen should fix your problem, since the OS won't do any upscaling then. Just a guess, though.

Comment: no, I'm not using a High DPI screen.  thanks for commenting. :)

Comment: so, Are you supposed to be able to see the custom holocrons easily?  I can barely see them when I look in the custom menu.

Comment: I noticed that the images you uploaded are both 1280x1024. It's entirely possible that the game designers made it with 16:9 aspect ratio in mind and neglected to fine tune it for 4:3 monitors. The opposite complaint was made about many games made for 4:3 monitors when displayed on a 16:9 monitor. Perhaps someone with another 4:3 monitor setup will be able to reproduce this scenario.